# spring boot file uploading executes twice when MultipartException occurs

Tags: file-upload, spring-boot

I want to upload files using spring-boot, and I have configured the properties right, and I also ensure the controller is correct, but the strange thing is the controller executed twice when I tried to upload a file larger exceed the limitation, what I expect is an error json message, and what I got is no response under the Postman.

Here is my controller,

```
@RestController
public class FileUploadController implements HandlerExceptionResolver {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadController.class);

    private static final String UPLOAD_PATH = "upload";

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public String upload(final MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            final Result<String> result = new Result<>();
            if (file.isEmpty()) {
                result.setSuccess(false);
                result.setMessage("file is empty");
                return Constants.OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(result);
            }

            final File outputFile = new File(UPLOAD_PATH, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(outputFile, file.getBytes());

            result.setSuccess(true);
            result.setMessage(outputFile.toString());
            return Constants.OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(result);
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return ExceptionResultBuilder.build(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler, final Exception ex) {
        final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setView(new MappingJackson2JsonView());
        final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("success", false);
        if (ex instanceof MultipartException) {
            // if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.info(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            // }
            final Throwable rootCause = ((MultipartException) ex).getRootCause();
            if (rootCause instanceof SizeLimitExceededException) {
                map.put("message", "request too large");
            } else if (rootCause instanceof FileSizeLimitExceededException) {
                map.put("message", "file too large");
            } else {
                map.put("message", "其他异常: " + rootCause.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        modelAndView.addAllObjects(map);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

and this is my property snippet for file uploading,

```
# MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
multipart.enabled=true
multipart.max-file-size=5Mb
multipart.max-request-size=10Mb
```

If I tried to upload a file a bit larger than 5M, I will get the result like below under Postman, (the file size is 5208k)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXTrJ.jpg)
and if I tried to upload a file between 5M and 10M, I will get this error, (the file size is 9748k)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtgqf.jpg)

I debugged into the controller and found that the resolveException method executed twice in a single upload.

Does anybody give me some tip?

Comment: You are using ModelAndView in a RestController, that is wrong.

Comment: I updated the code using the ControllerAdvice, there is no difference between the two implementations

Comment: Was this ever solved? Facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

The latest code list here, and I still got the same result,

```
@RestController
@ControllerAdvice
public class FileUploadController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadController.class);

    private static final String UPLOAD_PATH = "upload";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public HttpEntity<?> upload(final MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            final Result<String> result = new Result<>();
            if (file == null || file.isEmpty()) {
                result.setSuccess(false);
                result.setMessage("上传的文件为空");
                return new ResponseEntity<Result<?>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
            }

            final File outputFile = new File(UPLOAD_PATH, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(outputFile, file.getBytes());

            result.setSuccess(true);
            result.setMessage(outputFile.toString());
            return new ResponseEntity<Result<?>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return ExceptionResultBuilder.build(ex);
        }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
    public HttpEntity<?> multipartExceptionHandler(final MultipartException exception) {
        LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        try {
            final Result<String> result = new Result<>();
            result.setSuccess(false);

            final Throwable rootCause = ((MultipartException) exception).getRootCause();
            if (rootCause instanceof SizeLimitExceededException) {
                result.setMessage("请求过大");
            } else if (rootCause instanceof FileSizeLimitExceededException) {
                result.setMessage("文件过大");
            } else {
                result.setMessage("未知错误");
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<Result<?>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return ExceptionResultBuilder.build(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just go the same error and fix it by add the flowing code to my controller, good luck

```
@ExceptionHandler({ MultipartException.class, FileSizeLimitExceededException.class,
        SizeLimitExceededException.class })
public ResponseEntity<Attachment> handleUploadrException(HttpServletRequest request, Throwable ex) {
    Attachment result = new Attachment();
    result.setDescription(ex.getMessage());
    HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);
    return new ResponseEntity<Attachment>(result, status);
}



private HttpStatus getStatus(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
    if (statusCode == null) {
        return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
    return HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode);
}
```